# CPU constantly near 100% and computer overheating after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, cpu, overheating

It's definitely not a hardware issue, as it only started right after the upgrade, but there are no programs detected by the system monitor that use any significant amount of CPU.

> **Edit:** It seems there are two Xorg processes running at the same time, one from my user and another from `gdm`. The problem solves
>   itself if I kill one or the other... The only hick is that I had to do
>   that everytime I booted.
>
> I switched to lightdm and rebooted. This solved the problem. Now there
>   is only one Xorg process, owned by the user `root`, which is kind of
>   confusing... Should I report that as a GDM bug?

[image: System Monitor | Processes]
[image]

Comment: Click the hamburger menu in the upper right, and select _Active Processes_ instead perhaps, or _All Processes_ if it's not showing up under active. The default view is only for processes running as your user.

Comment: @dobey Xorg uses 33% of CPU, rsyslogd and systemd-journald use around 23%. Could it be that? What can I do about them?

Comment: Do they stay at that amount? Xorg is going to use more CPU while system monitor is open, because of the constant redraws. I'm not sure why the other two are using that much CPU, but even so, that doesn't add up to the ~315% CPU usage your screenshot shows.

Comment: Could it be additive (as in 30% of _all_ CPUs)?

Either way, these values do stay more or less the same...

Comment: It could possibly be an issue with your graphics card... I would try and use a different driver in the additional drivers tab in software and updates

Comment: Click on the cpu % heading until the triangle points up to see the heavy users at the top.

Comment: No, not additive in the way I think you're thinking of. If a process had 4 threads, each on a different core, and each thread was using 30%, it'd be 120% usage, when viewed collapsed. But with 4 cores, you still have 280% of the operating room left.  120% would increase temperature, but nowhere near as much as 300+% usage would, the latter of which is shown as occurring in your screenshot.

Comment: @ubfan1 Did that. Those are the only processes that use more than 1% CPU.

Comment: @dobey Well, that makes no sense then, because the problem was solved when I killed the Xorg process (see my edit). I "solved" my problem, but I'm kind of confused as to what was going wrong in the first place.

Comment: Then it seems perhaps there is some gdm bug which is causing the lock screen Xorg to consume extraneous CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to have been caused by a gdm bug that was creating a duplicate Xorg process. I switched to lightdm and the problem went away.

- **Step 1:** *Install lightdm if it isn't installed on your machine*

In the terminal, type

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Then enter your password

- **Step 2:** *Switch from GDM for lightdm (this will change how your login screen appears)*

In the terminal, type

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then select lightdm in the menu that appears using the arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

I've just created following script, which automatically kills second Xorg process. Works fine for me. can be run from root crontab, every minute, or some other way after user login:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# automatically kills second Xorg process

PID_GDM=$(ps -ef | grep Xorg | grep -v grep | grep "^gdm" | awk '{print $2}')
PID_USER=$(ps -ef | grep Xorg | grep -v grep | grep -v "^gdm" | awk '{print $2}')
if [ ! -z "$PID_GDM" ] && [ ! -z "$PID_USER" ]
then
    echo Killing $PID_GDM 
    kill -9 $PID_GDM 
fi
```